# Javascript not executing on JSP forward action

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jsp

Hi I have one jsp page and I have to update two html select boxes with the data of an inf file. On selecting the first combo(initially also not loading the second combo), the second will have to change accordingly. Since java script variable is not accessible from java, I had sent the value of first combo to an another jsp by ajax. And then return it to first jsp itself.Plaese help me.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm getting it wrong but looking at your code it seems that you are doing AJAX request on selectbox change event, but you are not doing anything with the response.
So basically what happens is you are doing an initial render to your jsp and everything is fine. Now you are changing selectbox option and AJAX request is sent to dummy.jsp. dummy.jsp is receiving it and redirecting the maker of the request to User.jsp. User.jsp-s content is sent back but nothing is done on the client side AJAX call with this response.

What you should do is have your logic at dummy.jsp(or even better at some servlet) which based on your AJAX call request parameters returns for example a JSON with data that you can process in jQuery.ajax success event. In there you can use this JSON to readjust your selectboxes and other data with javascript.
Check the examples at the end of jQuery.ajax manual: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: the ajax response is the html body. not what I want. That is why did like this